# Isotope with Infinite Scroll

Tags: plugin-jetpack, infinite-scroll

Using Jetpack Infinite Scroll & Isotope (Masonry).

I am facing an issue where after every new ajaxed set of posts, I need to `destroy` and then `build` isotope layout. If I don't go with this approach the new set of posts loaded by infinite scroll each time are not treated by isotope layout as its own and they miss on isotope styling. So, I need to rebuild isotope every time on `post-load` trigger of infinite scroll.

This approach actually leaves the user with a flick effect and scrolls to the beginning of isotope layout.

```
//In functions.php
function vg_infinite_scroll_init() {
    add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
        'container'         => 'row-wrap',
        'type'               => 'scroll',
        'render'            => 'loop_p_arch_infinite_scroll_render',
        'footer'            => false,
        'footer_widgets'     => false,
        'wrapper'            => false,
        'posts_per_page'    => 9,
    ) );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'vg_infinite_scroll_init' );

function loop_p_arch_infinite_scroll_render() {

    while( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
            get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
    }

}

function vg_get_prod_arch_posts( $post_type = 'post' ) {

    $prodarch_posts = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts'     => 9,
        'paged'         => get_query_var( 'paged' ),        
        'post_type'       => $post_type
    ) );

    return $prodarch_posts;

}

// In archive-product.php
<!-- Isotope Grid -->
<section id="product_list">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="grid" id="row-wrap">
                        <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
                        <?php
                        $products = vg_get_prod_arch_posts( 'product' );

                        if ( ! empty( $products ) ) {
                            foreach ( $products as $product ) { 

                            setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] = $product );
                            get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

                            }
                            wp_reset_postdata();
                        }
                        ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

//In content-product.php
global $post;
?>
<div class="grid-item post product">
    <div class="item_content">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="item_name"> 
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?> </h4> 
            </div>
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'large', array( 'class' => 'image_width_set' ) ); ?>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

//In JS file

jQuery(document).on("post-load", function(e) {
    jQuery('.grid').isotope('destroy');
    jQuery('.grid').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        percentPosition: true,
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
            gutter: 5
        }
    });
});

jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery('.grid').imagesLoaded(function() {
        jQuery('.grid').isotope({
            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
            percentPosition: true,
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
                gutter: 5
            }
        });
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually isotope allows appending new items and then just re-layout the masonry again:

Somewhere in your JS file you should put the elements you want to append into a variable, e.g. `new_elements`

```
jQuery('.grid').append(new_elements)
    .isotope('appended', new_elements)
    .imagesLoaded( function() {
        jQuery('.grid').istotope('layout');
    });
```

Source: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/methods.html

## The solution

*Thanks to @vajrasar for the final touches.*

When you echo the Grid-Page Loop, add the following:

```
function loop_p_arch_infinite_scroll_render() {
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );
    ?>
    <div id="page-<?=$paged?>">
        <?php while( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    <script id="script-page-<?=$paged?>">
        jQuery('document').ready(function($) {
            var new_elements = $('#page-<?=$paged?>').children('.grid-item');
            $('.grid')
                .append(new_elements)
                .isotope('appended', new_elements)
                .imagesLoaded( function() {
                    $('.grid').isotope('layout');
                });
            $('#page-<?=$paged?>, #script-page-<?=$paged?>').remove();
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: I know, but the problem is that there is no way with Infinite Scroll where I can fetch the next set of posts in an array or something.

Comment: usually there should be hooks u can use.. if u don't find any go through the code that handles the isotope implementation and post the relevant lines. **edit** found it... will edit when i got  a bigger screen. ;)

Comment: vajrasar, have you tried the improvements?

Comment: thanks for the code. I implemented it as is but it gave blank screen and also there was a typo in isotope spelling. But logic was bang on. Hence, I modified the code a bit and finally got it working. 

https://gist.github.com/vajrasar/359fbb4a89e68f1bd1d5

Please update your code to reflect this. I accepted it as THE answer. Thanks a lot for helping! :) Cheers.

Comment: @vajrasar glad to help. sorry for the typo, wrote it from scratch… no jetpack. ;) if you can point me to the mistakes, i would be glad to correct them.

Comment: I just fired the remove #page line in the later stage of the code after the whole isotope layout is set. Also, I appended the child elements which gets added inside the #page div, directly to the isotope .grid section and then fired the remove line of jquery. Its tough to explain in words so if possible can you please look at the gist that I gave you the link of in above comment.

Comment: @vajrasar bugs should be fixed. :)

Comment: I will be putting up a tut soon on this. Cheers!